# Can't index parsed JSON string from backend, it returns an undefined value

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, typescript

My frontend's supposed to take in a JSON string from the backend and use it, but when I try to index it after using `JSON.parse()`, it returns `undefined`. I checked, and it isn't inside an array either; it's just a JSON object literal.

In case any of you aren't familiar with TypeScript, the exclamation points are a TS thing, and removing them doesn't change the results I've been getting.

Here's what the console's been showing me:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('guestUserCredentials')!.textContent!)

"{\"EMAIL\": \"guest_user@foo.com\", \"PASSWORD\": \"foobar\"}"
```

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('guestUserCredentials')!.textContent!))

{"EMAIL": "guest_user@foo.com", "PASSWORD": "foobar"}
```

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('guestUserCredentials')!.textContent!)["EMAIL"])

undefined
```

Maybe it has something to do with the way my Django backend is encoding the JSON string? How do I check for that and fix it, if that's the case? I'm passing it to my React/TS frontend like this:

`settings.py`

```py
...
GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS = {
    'EMAIL': os.environ.get('GUEST_EMAIL'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('GUEST_PASSWORD'),
}
...
```

`views.py`

```py
import json

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request, *args, **kwargs):

  print(settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS)
  print(json.dumps(settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS))

  return render(request, 'index.html', context={
    'GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS': json.dumps(settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS),
  })
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='icon' href='{% static "frontend/favicon.ico" %}' type='image/x-icon' />
  <title>foo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='root'>
  <!-- React goes here. -->
</div>
</body>
{{ GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS|json_script:"guestUserCredentials" }}
<script src='{% static "frontend/index.bundle.js" %}'></script>
</html>
```

Maybe it has to do with the way the `json_script` template tag escapes certain characters in the JSON string? [I can't find anything about how that might affect the output in the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

Here's the output of the two `print()` commands in `views.py`:

```py
print(settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS)

{'EMAIL': 'guest_user@foo.com', 'PASSWORD': 'foobar'}
```

```py
print(json.dumps(settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS))

{"EMAIL": "guest_user@foo.com", "PASSWORD": "foobar"}
```

I even tried parsing the JSON string with `destr` instead of `JSON.parse()` and the result is still the same. This has been so frustrating.

Comment: Your code works for me in Javascript.  I can do `JSON.parse(s)['EMAIL']` or `JSON.parse(s).EMAIL`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried both already, both return `undefined`. Did you pass the string from a Django backend like in the example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried wrapping the output of `JSON.parse()` in another call to `JSON.parse()`, and I was able to index the resulting object the way I wanted to.

I'm not sure I fully understand what was going on, but I guess there was no need to run `json.dumps()` in my `views.py` file since `settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS` was already JSON.

Removing `json.dumps()` from `views.py` and adding `settings.GUEST_USER_CREDENTIALS` to context as-is removes the need for two calls to `JSON.parse()` in the frontend, and now everything's working as expected.